# Oracle Database 10g to .Net types with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using EF5 with this Oracle Provider :

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0,             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

I have a column name BSO_KEYI with the type Number(10).
I was trying to use the type long for my POCO.

The following request was generated :

```
SELECT
"Limit1"."C1" AS "C1",
"Limit1"."C2" AS "C2",
"Limit1"."C3" AS "C3",
"Limit1"."C4" AS "C4",
"Limit1"."BSO_TYPEVC" AS "BSO_TYPEVC",
"Limit1"."C5" AS "C5",
"Limit1"."C6" AS "C6",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC" AS "BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC",
"Limit1"."C7" AS "C7",
"Limit1"."LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT" AS "LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT",
"Limit1"."CREATION_DATEDT" AS "CREATION_DATEDT"
FROM ( SELECT
    "Extent1"."BSO_TYPEVC" AS "BSO_TYPEVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC" AS "BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC",
    "Extent1"."LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT" AS "LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT",
    "Extent1"."CREATION_DATEDT" AS "CREATION_DATEDT",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_KEYI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C1",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_TYPEI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C2",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_NUMERATION_BROADCASTI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C3",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_NUMERATION_MASTERI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C4",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_MASTER_KEYI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C5",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_MASTER_SCHEDULE_KEYI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C6",
     CAST( "Extent1"."LAST_MODIFICATION_UIDI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C7"
    FROM "Foo"."XO_BS_OBJECT" "Extent1"
    WHERE (( CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_KEYI" AS number(19,0))) = :p__linq__0) AND (ROWNUM <= (2) )
)  "Limit1"
```

After that I tried int and the following request was generated

```
SELECT
"Limit1"."C1" AS "C1",
"Limit1"."C2" AS "C2",
"Limit1"."C3" AS "C3",
"Limit1"."C4" AS "C4",
"Limit1"."BSO_TYPEVC" AS "BSO_TYPEVC",
"Limit1"."C5" AS "C5",
"Limit1"."C6" AS "C6",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC",
"Limit1"."BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC" AS "BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC",
"Limit1"."C7" AS "C7",
"Limit1"."LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT" AS "LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT",
"Limit1"."CREATION_DATEDT" AS "CREATION_DATEDT"
FROM ( SELECT
    "Extent1"."BSO_TYPEVC" AS "BSO_TYPEVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ALTERNATIVEVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_BROADCASTVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_ORIGINALVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC" AS "BSO_TITLE_PRESSVC",
    "Extent1"."BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC" AS "BSO_APPROX_LENGTHVC",
    "Extent1"."LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT" AS "LAST_MODIFICATION_DATEDT",
    "Extent1"."CREATION_DATEDT" AS "CREATION_DATEDT",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_KEYI" AS number(10,0)) AS "C1",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_TYPEI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C2",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_NUMERATION_BROADCASTI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C3",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_NUMERATION_MASTERI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C4",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_MASTER_KEYI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C5",
     CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_MASTER_SCHEDULE_KEYI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C6",
     CAST( "Extent1"."LAST_MODIFICATION_UIDI" AS number(19,0)) AS "C7"
    FROM "Foo"."XO_BS_OBJECT" "Extent1"
    WHERE (( CAST( "Extent1"."BSO_KEYI" AS number(10,0))) = :p__linq__0) AND (ROWNUM <= (2) )
)  "Limit1"
```

As you can see with type long, EF cast the column as NUMBER(19,0) and with int there is a cast to the same type in the database Number(10,0).
Is the cast breaking the index on this column ? Is there a better .Net type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we switch to Devart provider and it works way better (same C# type but doesn't generate cast).
We passed from 3s to 0.4s.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember the natural mapping of a Number (x, y) would be to a decimal (or float, double). As for your "cast ignores the index" question the database should be smart enough to use it.